# unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'map' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, lambda

I have many column in my data Frame. From these many column I have usage of two column income_ and salary_score.
I have two find mean from salary_score column from each index and find Mean of them and assign two its respective income_ index.

### **Value in Column.**

1) INCOME_ = NULL.
2) SALARY_SCORE = 70-90K.

I am thinking to use a lambda function instead of for-each loop. I have tried with for loop but I want to look further with the help of Lambda functionality.

```
customers=pd.read_excel(path+'Customer Details.xlsx')
customers['INCOME_']=customers['SALARY_SCORE'].apply(lambda x:np.array(map(re.findall(r'\d+', x),int)).mean())
```

**Error**: Showing 
   ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
      else:
   ret = ret / rcount
   return ret

Comment: On Python 3 `map` no longer returns a `list`. So you need to cast to `list(map(...))` manually.

Comment: I have tried list(map(...)) ...Thanks Buddy It works....!